# SPA (Single-page app) load always from cache

Tags: caching, xmlhttprequest, sapui5, html5-appcache, application-cache

I have a SPA (Single-Page Application) written using OpenUI5 framework.
It works well (when I'm in debug mode or using cache-killer https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap) but now I have pushed the app on the server apache: here the problems started...

Users not have cache-killer installed and I would like update the app on the server and immediately have the new version of the app on the users pcs at the successive refresh.

In my app I have a series of tab: each tab have a content and I have two different content for each tab (a display fragment content and a change fragment content). 
When I load the page, by default, tabs are filled by display fragments; then I press a button and the content of each tab swithc to the change fragments.

[image]

The problem is that all fragment that I retrieve after the first page loading are loaded `(from cache)`...

I try to use manifest application cache and the various meta-tags (see [Chaching with single-page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474845/chaching-with-single-page-application)) but the problem not change and it is still there.

This is a request-response header for the diplay fragment (correcly loaded from the server)

```
General:

Request URL:http://10.7.1.96/www/temp_ftp_grunt/view/tab/article/TabAnagrDisplay.fragment.xml
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Response header:

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 14:45:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=46
ETag: "38b6-51ff07d7bfe81"

Request Header:

GET /www/temp_ftp_grunt/view/tab/article/TabAnagrDisplay.fragment.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.7.1.96
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://10.7.1.96/www/temp_ftp_grunt/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
If-None-Match: "38b6-51ff07d7bfe81"
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 12:24:01 GMT
```

and this for the change fragment loaded from cache

```
General:

Request URL:http://10.7.1.96/www/temp_ftp_grunt/view/tab/article/TabAnagrChange.fragment.xml
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)

Response header:

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:23642
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Thu, 17 Sep 2015 14:44:47 GMT
ETag:"5c5a-51ff1965857b1"
Last-Modified:Thu, 17 Sep 2015 13:42:33 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6"

Request Header:

Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Referer:http://10.7.1.96/www/temp_ftp_grunt/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**For OpenUI5 developers**: I have loaded the fragment in this moode:

1.display fragments in `onInit` function of the controller that contain the list of tabs

```
    var oTab = new sap.m.IconTabFilter();
            oTab.addContent(myfragment);
            tabBar.addItem(oTab);
```

2.change fragments by a function that remove the display frg by `tabBar.removeAllItems();` and add the new frg in the same mode of 1.

I have tried to find a solution to my problem; I have read this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching and this http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag articles but I can't find the solution for my problem. Cache buster https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f080966f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html suggested here [Force clear cache in OpenUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603161/force-clear-cache-in-openui5) require a SAP backend

Comment: See Apache cache refresh: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1207492/1469028

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and managed by defining a new path for fragments

```
sap.ui.localResources("fragments");
```

By default, fragments was in the same folder than Libraries (resources) and always caching.